# My ASP.NET desktop website layout isn't displaying properly on a mobile device

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

My ASP.NET desktop website works great on a desktop or laptop, the layout however doesn't adjust correctly on a mobile device. I've tried referencing Bootstrap in a link in html but it doesn't change it, I do have bootstrap.css in my Content folder and bootstrap.js in my scripts folder. I used a Blank Template to start my project as well. any advice would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Your ASP.NET application</title>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Did you use Bootstrap's grid system?

Comment: "I've tried referencing Bootstrap in a link in html but it doesn't change" — Bootstrap isn't magic. You have to write your HTML in such a way as to use the styles the stylesheet provides. Consult the Bootstrap manual to lean how to use it properly.

Comment: I am fully aware that Bootstrap isn't magic, I'm new to Bootstrap and I'm trying to get familiar with it. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @Anna Bootstrap does very little until you adapt your HTML to use its classes and HTML structure. Take a look at the HTML of the examples section on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ and http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for the responsive grid system.

Comment: Thank you, I will!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap CDN
The folks over at MaxCDN graciously provide CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. Just use these Bootstrap CDN links.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Did you use bootstrap 3

Bootstrap 3 is designed to be responsive to mobile devices. Mobile-first styles are part of the core framework.

To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming, add the following  tag inside the  element:

The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The initial-scale=1 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

Comment: "add the following tag" — The code in the question shows they have done that already.

Comment: I have bootstrap v3.3.6

Comment: I did add the width=device-width in a link in the header but no change. I'm not familiar with Bootstrap so this is very confusing for me.